# Save a lot of image in internal storage best practice

Tags: android, image, file, zip, android-internal-storage

I need to save on file internal storage directory a lot of images, so I have doubts about best practices to do this.

First, it is good to save all images on the archive file, or It worth saving just in a sub-directory? Extract the images when it needs is so annoying because needs to work with `InputStream` to read the files and this implicates a lot of computational time loss.
Meanwhile to read a file just need to specify the path, but there is a lot of file in the directory.

So which is the best way or which is the most worth?

Comment: A lot of images is how much about?

Comment: You are not even mentioning zipping and unzipping.

Answer (score 1):

Save your images as it is, you can make like more than one category folder and split your images between them. Also if your images are jpeg, png .. compressing them won't save you much space and it need more time  and work to decompress them.